# Properly distinguish between not set (nil) and blank/empty value

Tags: go

Whats the correct way in go to distinguish between when a value in a struct was never set, or is just empty, for example, given the following:

```
type Organisation struct {
    Category string
    Code     string
    Name     string
}
```

I need to know (for example) if the category was never set, or was saved as blank by the user, should I be doing this:

```
type Organisation struct {
    Category *string
    Code     *string
    Name     *string
}
```

I also need to ensure I correctly persist either `null` or an *empty string* to the database

I'm still learning GO so it is entirely possible my question needs more info.

Comment: In non-sql cases (such as when using `json.Unmarshal()` or most other Unmarshallers) using `*string` is a good way to go.

Answer (score 6):

The zero value for a `string` is an empty string, and you can't distinguish between the two.

If you are using the `database/sql` package, and need to distinguish between `NULL` and empty strings, consider using the `sql.NullString` type.  It is a simple struct that keeps track of the `NULL` state:

```
type NullString struct {
        String string
        Valid  bool // Valid is true if String is not NULL
}
```

You can scan into this type and use it as a query parameter, and the package will handle the `NULL` state for you.

Answer (score 5):

Google's protocol buffers (https://code.google.com/p/goprotobuf/) use pointers to describe optional fields.

The generated objects provide `GetFoo` methods which take the pain away from testing for nil (`a.GetFoo()` returns an empty string if `a.Foo` is nil, otherwise it returns `*a.Foo`).

It introduces a nuisance when you want to write literal structs (in tests, for example), because `&"something"` is not valid syntax to generate a pointer to a string, so you need a helper function (see, for example, [the source code of the protocol buffer library for `proto.String`](https://code.google.com/p/goprotobuf/source/browse/proto/lib.go#339)).

```
// String is a helper routine that allocates a new string value
// to store v and returns a pointer to it.
func String(v string) *string {
        return &v
}
```

Overall, using pointers to represent optional fields is not without drawbacks, but it's certainly a viable design choice.

Answer (score 4):

The standard [`database/sql`](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) package provides a [`NullString`](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString) struct (members are just `String string` and `Valid bool`). To take care of some of the repetitive work of persistence, you could look at an object-relational manager like [gorp](https://github.com/coopernurse/gorp/).

I looked into whether there was some way to distinguish two kinds of empty string just out of curiosity, and couldn't find one. With `[]byte`s, `[]byte{} == []byte(nil)` currently returns false, but I'm not sure if the spec guarantees that to always remain true. In any case, it seems like the most practical thing to do is to go with the flow and use `NullString`.